# Picture from virtual directory IIS won't load

Tags: iis, virtual-directory

When I enter an order number in a search bar, an image with the name "ordernummer".jpg must be retrieved. For this I use a web page that runs on an IIS server. For this I have already created a virtual directory to access the nas. The problem now is that the image will not load anyway.

The error I get:

[image]

Comment: Please check if the folder matches the path of the virtual directory.

Comment: I checked this, the path is the one I need. This is not the problem. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Make sure your account has sufficient permissions to access the UNC path or you can try to use the true physical path instead of the UNC path.